# Little bit of trouble with my MySQL query

Tags: mysql

[My MySQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tET9n.jpg)

Ok so I'm trying to add another column (leave_remaining) that will display that if the leave_status is 'ok' then the leave_remaining will show the number of leave days that employee has left.  I keep getting errors with this.  What is the right syntax here?  Thank you

**This works:**

```
select id,leave_started,leave_ended,no_of_leave_allowed, 
leave_ended-leave_started AS no_of_leaves_taken, 
if (leave_ended-leave_started >no_of_leave_allowed, 
 'leave exceeded','ok')as leave_status
from leave_taken;
```

**This does not:**

```
if (leave_status,'ok', 
(no_leave_allowed-no_leaves_taken))as leave_remaining
 from leave_taken;
select * from leave_taken;
```

Comment: Please add your query to the question in text format

Comment: What are the errors?  What are you expecting to get?  What are you getting instead?

Comment: It's saying unknown column for leave_status.  Also if is not valid at that position

Comment: Also I'm just expecting to get to number of leave days remaining in a new column named leave_remaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you properly, I think you want this:

```
SELECT
    id, leave_started, leave_ended, no_of_leave_allowed, 
    (leave_ended - leave_started) AS no_of_leaves_taken, 
    IF(
        (leave_ended - leave_started) > no_of_leave_allowed,
        'leave exceeded',
        'ok'
    ) AS leave_status,
    IF (
        (leave_ended - leave_started) > no_of_leave_allowed,
        (no_of_leave_allowed - (leave_ended - leave_started)),
        0
    ) AS leave_remaining
FROM leave_taken;
```

Though not sure how you have defined `leave_started` and `leave_ended` that you can subtract them like that...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16cdb3/6

Answer (score 0):

SELECT has to be before the IF, altough you are not doing anything.

The correct statement is

```
SELECT something as alias, something_else as alias_else, if(,,) as alias_if
FROM table
WHERE where = clause
```

When you have to use some statement (IF or CASE for example), that result in a field, it has to be inside a select.